# How can I find Parse User's Facebook Information in swift?

Tags: facebook, swift, parse-platform

I am using Parse loginViewController to Log In the User via Facebook. I just cant figure out how to call the Graph API in Swift. I found the following on Parse

```
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:(PFUseruser, NSError error) { if (user) {

    [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
            // Store the current user's Facebook ID on the user
            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[result objectForKey:@"id"]
                         forKey:@"fbId"];
            [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
         }
    }];
} }];
```

But I cant seem to translate it into Swift. I am trying to run this inside the following function:

```
func logInViewController(controller: PFLogInViewController, didLogInUser user: PFUser) -> Void
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, didLogInUser user: PFUser!) -> Void
{
    FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler({connection, result, error in
        if !error
        {
            PFUser.currentUser().setObject(result.id as? String, forKey: "fbId")
            PFUser.currentUser().saveInBackground()
        }
        else
        {
            println("Error")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: `FBRequestConnection.startForPostOpenGraphObject(graphObject, ({connection, result, error in if!error{} }))` giving error **Cannot convert expression's type 'FBRequestConnection' to 'Void'**

Comment: @Matt your solution is close but does not work. For one the compiler does not accept `!error` secondly in the line `PFUser.currentUser().setObject(result.id as? String, forKey: "fbId")` does not compile either firstly I had to change `result.id` to `result.objectId` and second it keeps throwing an error at `as?` giving me a fatal error for unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional. Leads me to believe it is force unwrapping an optional somewhere

Answer (score 0):

```
func getFBData(user: PFUser!){
    FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler({connection, result, error in
        if (error != nil) {
            println(result)
        }else {
            println("Error")
        }
    })
}
```